# Merge multiple dataframes with matching and different columns and put NA's

Tags: r, merge

I have 5 dataframes with different subsets of variables. For example, the subset of the 5 A-Variables appear in dataframe 1 and 5. The subset of the 7 B-Variables appear in dataframe 1 and 4 and so on. A different number of persons did one of the 5 test-versions (thats why I have 5 dataframes)

Now, I want to merge the dataframes together. The colums shall have all variables of all dataframes. When a variable appeared in two dataframes, the values should be merged and appear in one column at the end. For all persons who did not see a variable because it was in another test, a "NA" should be in there at the end..

Do you guys have an idea?

Thank you very much in advance!

Comment: Hi can you provide any code you've tried, and data to go with it? Also: https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll probably need to do some combination of `inner_join()`, `left_join()`, `right_join()` etc.

Check [this](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/join.html) out, should have what you need... It's difficult to know exactly what you need without seeing the data.